# Why Isn't EmailConfig.Host Retrieving Configuration from appsettings.json in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I retrieve the configuration settings from `appsettings.json` or `appsettings.Development.json`? I've attempted to do so using dependency injection with the following code (dotnet7, minimal api):

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<EmailConfig>();
builder.Services.Configure<EmailConfig>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Email"));
```

However, when I try to print `EmailConfig.Host` using `Console.WriteLine("bla", EmailConfig.Host);`, nothing is displayed, and there are no errors. What might be missing here?

Here are the contents of `appsettings.Development.json`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Email": {
    "Host": "google"
  }
}
```

And here are the contents of `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Email": {
    "Host": "google"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Here's the relevant code from `program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddTransient<EmailConfig>();
builder.Services.Configure<EmailConfig>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Email"));

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

And here's the `EmailConfig.cs` class:

```
public class EmailConfig
{
    public string Host { get; set; }
}
```

In the `WeatherForecastController.cs`, I'm trying to access the `EmailConfig` like this:

```
public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, EmailConfig emailConfig)
{
    _logger = logger;
    EmailConfig = emailConfig;
}

[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
    Console.WriteLine("bla", EmailConfig.Host);
    // ...
}
```

However, the value of `EmailConfig.Host` is not being printed. What could be the issue?

Comment: I've removed your minimal-apis tag because you're not using minimal APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two problems here:

1. You're registering `EmailConfig` with `builder.Services.AddTransient<EmailConfig>();`. This is not necessary.
2. You're configuring the options `EmailConfig` but not injecting the options.

To clarify: `Configure` doesn't configure a previously-registered service. It adds something to configure an `EmailConfig`. To use this `EmailConfig` you need to inject it using `IOptions<EmailConfig>` or similar.

So remove the registration from 1, and then inject the options like so:

```
public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, IOptions<EmailConfig> emailConfig)
```

Now `emailConfig.Value` is an instance of `EmailConfig`.

You can learn more about the options pattern and related injectables [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0).